# Subir imagenes png al servidor

Tags: php, jquery, html5, css3

Estoy desrrollando un aplicativo con **html5**, **css3**, **jquery** y **php**, y tengo el problema de que cuando quiero subir una imagen png, no la sube al servidor. Puedo subir imagenes jpg, bmp, pero cuando la imagen es png parece que no la detecta. ¿Alguna idea porque pasa esto?

Este es el codigo que us: el arcbivo temporal si lo crea pero no lo sube, parece que el problema esta en la setencia mov_upload. Lo raro es que si funciona con otros tipo de imagenes. el problema es solo "png"

```
//revisa si viene imagen
if ($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]!=""){
    echo $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];

    //verifica tipo de imagen, capturando la extension del nombre del archivo
    //vrifica la posocion del punto (.), para los archivos jpeg
    $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4);
    if (substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4, 1)!="."){
        $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -5);
    }
    $ext=substr($ext, 1); //quita el punto de la extension

    if($ext=="jpeg" or $ext=="jpg" or $ext=="bmp"){
        $imagen=time() . ".$ext";

        $destino="media.image/publicacion/" . $imagen;
        $archivo=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

        move_uploaded_file($archivo, $destino);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar lo que haz realizado?

Comment: Tendrías que incluir en tu `if` la condición  `or $ext=="png"`

Comment: Coincido con @FranciscoRomero. Falta or `$ext=="png"` en la condición.

Comment: Listo, gracias, ya vi el error.

Answer (score 3):

Como indican en los comentarios, tu problema es agregar una condición más a tu *if*.

```
//revisa si viene imagen
if ($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]!=""){
    echo $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];

    //verifica tipo de imagen, capturando la extension del nombre del archivo
    //vrifica la posocion del punto (.), para los archivos jpeg
    $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4);
    if (substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4, 1)!="."){
        $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -5);
    }
    $ext=substr($ext, 1); //quita el punto de la extension

    if($ext=="jpeg" or $ext=="jpg" or $ext=="bmp" or $ext=="png"){
        $imagen=time() . ".$ext";

        $destino="media.image/publicacion/" . $imagen;
        $archivo=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

        move_uploaded_file($archivo, $destino);
    }
}
```

---

Otra forma de validar y que no te compliques, es usar un Array en el cual tendrá todos tus extensiones "válidas" y usando la función [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) validas que esté contenida en dichas extensiones.

Por ejemplo:

```
//revisa si viene imagen
if ($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]!=""){
    echo $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];

    //verifica tipo de imagen, capturando la extension del nombre del archivo
    //vrifica la posocion del punto (.), para los archivos jpeg
    $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4);
    if (substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -4, 1)!="."){
        $ext=substr($_FILES["archivo"]["name"], -5);
    }

    $ext = substr($ext, 1); //quita el punto de la extension

    $extensionesValidas = array("jpeg", "jpg", "bmp", "png");

    if(in_array($ext, $extensionesValidas)){
        $imagen=time() . ".$ext";

        $destino="media.image/publicacion/" . $imagen;
        $archivo=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

        move_uploaded_file($archivo, $destino);
    }
}
```

Asimismo, puedes aprovechar el atributo `accept` en tu input file.

```
<input type="file" name="archivo" accept="image/*">
```

Ahí indica que permitirá visualizar y seleccionar los archivos de tipo imagen.

En caso quieras especificar los tipos:

```
<input type="file" name="archivo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png">
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [in_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)
- [HTML  accept Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)